# mt9p111 initialization

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, stm32, camera

I need to use mt9p111 (LI-5M05CM-AF), but I can't find any initialization examples in Internet. I found drivers for linux and android at github: (Link in comments).

I didn't see any results of mt9p111 initialization with I2C. A sent registers table but didn't see any data on cam data bus.

Sun time later I saw, that serial interface not initialized (look upper linc, code string 3278) and tryed to change it to parallel. But I didn't see any data again.

Should I switch on data exchange, wrigting some command in some register? Later I reduced init code http://pastebin.com/Zyv2zPfY

Here is datasheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1V89BcPR7z7RmlnWDRhLVdoem8/view

Comment: github: https://github.com/pio-masaki/android-kernel-at1s0/blob/84c8e4925e2f8bef21a24ed02f965f1e11dca075/drivers/media/video/tegra/mt9p111_reg-scorpio.h

Comment: Probably all afraid of the amount of code, lol